# Account number supressed on a deposit receipt

Tags: receipt, banking

My bank issues deposit receipts with most of the account number blocked out, claiming security concerns. ( Account Number * * * * * * * 1234 ). How useful to me is such a receipt, if not useful is the bank allowed to do this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually there is a transaction number.

Even if there isn't, your name, last four digits and other info should be sufficient to establish the receipt as representative of the transaction.